# PHP find files on a network share

Tags: php, path

I am trying to find a way to access to a specified folder located on a network share

I tried that

```
        $lector = '\\\\my.local.ip\\WebUpload\\';
        $folder = $data[1];
        //Sanitize to remove unwanted white space
        $lector = trim($lector);            
        $folder = trim($folder);

        $path = $lector.$folder;

        if(!file_exists($path)) {
          print "$path: does not exist\n";
        }
```

I can access it when I type it in the windows execute tool. (\\10.8.7.1\WebUpload\201503042103_8)

The `$path` is well shown as `\\10.8.7.1\WebUpload\201503042103_8`

Comment: Found a blog post that explains what is going on [link](http://awesometoast.com/php-and-mapped-network-drives/)

Comment: @JasonK This was the answer. Thanks !